# What is a word for when someone tries to hide their fear?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe it when a person who is afraid hides their fear. Going by [this online dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bravado), `BRAVADO` is close. However, I'm looking for something with a more positive connotation, like where the intention is not to impress others or the person isn't being brash or thoughtlessly endangering themselves.

Comment: Just to clarify: you did place an emphasis on the fact this person is not *courageous*  whatsoever but just hides his/her emotions and at the same time does not want to boast, didn't you? What if we merely say this person is *stoic* or *inscrutable*? For example: "He looks blankly inscrutable regardless this big bully is about to start a fight".

Comment: Not really. My character would actually be courageous.

Comment: Do you mean like 'keep a stiff upper lip'? That's a bit British innit.

Comment: Thank you for asking. A word request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a “right” answer. Please [edit] to include the desired register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say "stoic" fits the description.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoic

Look at the adjective definition.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the phrase ***gird oneself for***. Girding oneself is the process of mentally preparing for a difficult task of some kind. This is typically a completely internal process that's done to steady oneself and avoid panic, and not to impress others. An individual girding themselves for an upcoming battle would hide their fear and behave courageously.

Answer (score 1):

***to put on a brave face*** is a phrasal verb meaning:

> pretend to be calm; conceal one’s fears.
>   Also *to put on a bold front*.
>   [Bloomsbury Dictionary of Idioms](https://books.google.com/books?id=svfo4CW1GTMC&pg=PT347&dq=%22put+on+a+brave+face%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPv_-t-b_eAhU_HTQIHS_1C3YQ6AEIOTAE#v=onepage&q=%22put%20on%20a%20brave%20face%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **unfazed**

From the [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unfazed):

> Not disconcerted or perturbed.
>
> ‘the protestors were unfazed by the prospect of arrest’

When a given person is *unfazed* in the face of fear this does not imply foolhardiness but merely means he or she is able to effectively cope with bad emotions (for instance fear) and does not display them. Here is an example of usage from a real [news article](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4456170/Jimmy-John-s-employee-remains-unfazed-armed-robbery.html):

> Jimmy John's employee looks unfazed as robber points gun at his head